# Sum expenses and income based on date and category

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, lets try to explain as easy as possible. I have an excel workbook with two sheets in it. The first contains all transactions from your bank account.

> Comment; Date; Amount; Category
>
> Amazon; 17.01.2013; €33,24; Books

The second sheet is a multilevel table. Basically the columns are the month (in numbers and names) like 1/January, 2/February. The rows are the categories.

> Category; January/Expenses; January/Income; February/Expenses; February/Income
>
> Books; €33,24; €0; ....

The conditions for the sum are a) the category, b) amount less than zero (for expenses) or greater than zero (for income), c) the date greater than the first of the month and d) the date less than the first of the following month.

I tried working with SUMIFS or IF and then SUM. But I have problems adding the date-constraint. You can [download the spreadsheet here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10885415/Excel_SumIfs.xlsx).

Comment: One idea would be to break out your amount column in first sheet to two columns for income and expense (like a check book register).  Then you could use a pivot table on the second sheet more easily.

Comment: True, the Pivot-Chart is the optimal choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what the formula would be for **C5**:

> =SUMIFS(Umsätze!$C:$C,Umsätze!$F:$F,Übersicht!$B5,Umsätze!$B:$B,">="&DATE(Übersicht!$A$1,Übersicht!C$2,1),Umsätze!$B:$B,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(Übersicht!$A$1,Übersicht!C$2,1),0),Umsätze!$C:$C,IF(C$4="Income",">0","<0"))

As you have merged cells in row 2, this cannot be easily copied. The preferred setup would be row 2 having the month numbers without merged cells. This would make the row look like this:

```
1   1   2   2   3   3   4   ....
```

Then you can copy this formula across all rows/columns needed.

To check the date, the comparison used in the SUMIF is

```
Umsätze!$B:$B,">="&DATE(Übersicht!$A$1,Übersicht!C$2,1)
```

for a date greater or equal to the 1st of the month, and

```
Umsätze!$B:$B,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(Übersicht!$A$1,Übersicht!C$2,1),0)
```

for a date equal to or less than the end of the current month.

The use of the $ signs will ensure that the appropriate cells are referenced when the cells are copied - no change in columns for the Umsätze sheet, and making sure that the names only alter the row (`Übersicht!$B5`) and the month number only alters the column (`Übersicht!C$2`), the year being fixed into position with `Übersicht!$A$1`

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But the Pivot-Chart works even better.